Pinescript store value of high or low from candle that met a condition
To be clear: this could be a super simple fix. I just have a VERY basic understanding of pinescript that i would miss it if that was the case. In pinescript for tradingview I am trying to write an indicator that prints an arrow when a trade would be taken (for backtesting, with the intention of converting to a strategy later when this part is working.)
Video link for strategy reference:
https://youtu.be/eNo49lZb2Qc?si=0brI--ya517AeRcS
The issue I am having: I want to store the high of a bullish candle that closed above a previous bullish candle. When I try to store the "lvbull" after a condition is met it changes it to the high but then doesn't stay there until the next time that value would be broken, meeting the condition to add to the "candle count."
let me see if I can outline the rules for the strategy I need to have working:

I am looking for three candles in the same direction that would likely result in a pullback. The three candles do not need to be one right after the other, which is where the coding issues come in. For example, with a series of bullish candles, as long as a bearish candle does  not close below the low of the "last value candle," then the bullish series is still intact.

If the body of a candle closes above the wick of the previous candle (or the wick of a candle as outlined in rule 3) in a bullish 3 candle series, then the count advances.

If the high of any candle is higher than the "last value candle's" high, but the body does not close above that wick, then the new "last value candle" high is the highest wick before a body closes above that wick, adding to the "candle count"

If the body of a bearish candle closes below the low wick of the "last value candle" then the candle count resets to 0 and begins in favor of the new bearish 3 candle series.

Vice versa on all of that for bearish candle series.


an example of the code is below as well as a screenshot showing that the lvbull and lvbear values just travel with the highs and lows of the price action as opposed to staying stationary until broken.
//@version=5
indicator("Three Candle Fade", overlay=true)

// Define input variables
tf = input(defval = 240, title = "Timeframe", group = "Timeframe")
var int candle_count_bull = 0
var int candle_count_bear = 0
diffbull = candle_count_bull == 3 and close>open
diffbear = candle_count_bear == 3 and open>close

// Calculate OHLC of previous candles on 4-hour timeframe
prev_high = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", high[1])
prev_low = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", low[1])
prev_close = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", close[1])
prev_open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", open[1])
lvbull = high
lvbear = low

// Bearish state
if(close < lvbear and barstate.isconfirmed)
    candle_count_bear := candle_count_bear+1

else if(low < lvbull and close >= prev_high and close < prev_high and barstate.isconfirmed)
    lvbear := low

else if(close > lvbear and barstate.isconfirmed)
    candle_count_bear := 0


// Bullish state
if(close > lvbull and barstate.isconfirmed)
    candle_count_bull := candle_count_bull+1

else if(high > lvbull and close <= prev_low and close > prev_low and barstate.isconfirmed)
    lvbull := high

else if(close < lvbull and barstate.isconfirmed)
    candle_count_bull := 0

//plotshape(diffbull and barstate.isconfirmed, style = shape.arrowdown, size = size.large, color = color.red, location = location.abovebar)
//plotshape(diffbear and barstate.isconfirmed, style = shape.arrowup, size = size.large, color = color.green, location = location.belowbar)
plot(lvbull)
plot(lvbear)

image that shows the "lvbear" and "lvbull" values following price

You need to use var when declaring the variable, otherwise it will reset on every bar.
var lvbull = high
var lvbear = low


Sorry for the delayed response. I changed those to be variables but unfortunately it just made the plots disappear entirely.

They are still there, they are just likely not showing because they are far away from price. You need a way to reset them if price moves so far away. Look at the status line and you will see where they are plotted at.
